# Failure to link Qhull C++ interface in ROS catkin project

Tags: c++, ros, shared-objects, catkin, qhull

I'm having some trouble getting the QHull C++ interface working in a catkin project. My project compiles fine and I've specified the library to be used by the linker, however it fails to link with the following error messages.

```
CMakeFiles/path_to/my_code.cpp.o: In function `main':
my_code.cpp:(.text+0x17ab): undefined reference to `orgQhull::RboxPoints::RboxPoints()'
my_code.cpp:(.text+0x182a): undefined reference to `orgQhull::PointCoordinates::appendPoints(std::istream&)'
my_code.cpp:(.text+0x1839): undefined reference to `orgQhull::Qhull::Qhull()'
my_code.cpp:(.text+0x1857): undefined reference to `orgQhull::Qhull::runQhull(orgQhull::RboxPoints const&, char const*)'
my_code.cpp:(.text+0x18aa): undefined reference to `orgQhull::Qhull::outputQhull(char const*)'
my_code.cpp:(.text+0x19d0): undefined reference to `orgQhull::Qhull::~Qhull()'
my_code.cpp:(.text+0x19ee): undefined reference to `orgQhull::RboxPoints::~RboxPoints()'
my_code.cpp:(.text+0x1c10): undefined reference to `orgQhull::Qhull::~Qhull()'
my_code.cpp:(.text+0x1c38): undefined reference to `orgQhull::RboxPoints::~RboxPoints()'
CMakeFiles/build_path/my_code.cpp.o: In function `orgQhull::Qhull::setOutputStream(std::ostream*)':
```

I've installed the following packages, to get the shared object and development files.

- libqhull-dev
- libqhull-doc
- libqhull7
- qhull-bin

I don't know if this is related to the problem, but looking into the libqhull.so shared object there are no symbols in it.

```
####:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ nm -g libqhull.so
nm: libqhull.so: no symbols
```

Has anyone got any experience getting this to work on linux? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this is a linking problem, it would be helpful if you post your project CMakeLists file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using ROS Indigo, this works for me:

```
SET(qhullDir path_to_qhull_code)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${qhullDir}/src/libqhullcpp)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${qhullDir}/src)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${qhullDir}/build)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${qhullDir}/src/libqhullcpp)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(include)

SET(qhullLibs qhullcpp qhull_r)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_library
  src/myClass.cpp) 

add_executable(libExample
 src/myrunnable.cpp)
target_link_libraries(libExample
 ${PROJECT_NAME}_library ${qhullLibs})
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(libExample PROPERTIES
 COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "qh_QHpointer")
```

I'm compiling qhull from source with cmake.

Maybe this helps someone.